# Using dynamic list of objects in dapper join queries

Tags: c#, dapper

Is it possible to create the below written dapper query with returntype as `IEnumerable<dynamic>` as I do not have Product & Supplier POCO.

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = sqlConnection
                    .Query<Product, Supplier, Product>(
                        @"select Products.*, Suppliers.* 
                          from Products join Suppliers 
                               on Products.SupplierId = Suppliers.Id
                               and suppliers.Id = 2",
                        (a, s) =>
                            {
                                a.Supplier = s;
                                return a;
                            });
```

What if my sql query was something as below, how would my dapper query be with returntype of `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

```
select Products.ProductId,Products.ProductName,Products.ProductCategory, ProductPrice.Amount,ProductPrice.Currency
                              from Products join ProductPrice 
                                   on Products.ProductId = ProductPrice.ProductId
```

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can map the result of your queries to a list of dynamic objects (documentation [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#execute-a-query-and-map-it-to-a-list-of-dynamic-objects)).

```
    const string sql = @"select Products.ProductId, Products.ProductName, Products.ProductCategory, ProductPrice.Amount, ProductPrice.Currency
                        from Products join ProductPrice 
                        on Products.ProductId = ProductPrice.ProductId";

    IEnumerable<dynamic> products = sqlConnection.Query(sql);
```

In your first example you are doing [multi mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping) which maps each table row onto 2 objects instead of one (`Product` and `Supplier`) that are then linked by reference before the product is returned. I don't think you could do this with dynamic objects, because Dapper would have no way of knowing how to divide the columns among them. You could confirm this with a test, replacing generic parameters `<Product, Supplier, Product>` with `<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>`.

Skipping the multi-mapping would just mean that the `dynamic` objects returned would contain both `Product` and `Supplier` properties, which might not be a problem for you.